# How to stream large (~200mb) dynamically generated response in django?

Tags: django, csv, django-rest-framework, large-data

I have to generate a csv response from a large data set. The csv data is generated dynamically and rendered using djangorestframework-csv. 
But due to large size of the response the memory shoots up drastically and the browser also hangs in handling such large response.

```
class ImageLabelAnnotations(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    renderer_classes = (csvRenderer.CSVRenderer,)

    def get(self, request):
        result= []

        < database queries to generate the response > 

        return Response(result)
```

Sending the file as attachment doesn't help either.
I need to somehow stream this response to browser while keeping the memory in check as well on the server side.

Comment: look into StreamingHttpResponse, it will chunk and send your data. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

Comment: I tried using CSVStreamingRenderer which internally uses StreamHttpResponse. But still the rendering process is hanging on the browser.

Comment: Well that is expected since you are doing heavy processing during the request/response cycle. Any particular reason you want the csv to be part of the response cycle? Perhaps process the csv offline and send it to the user later?

Answer (score -2):

You Need to add like this

```
  CONTENT_TYPES = ['image', 'video']

   MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = "5242880"
```

For Reference Below screen-shot

[image]

Comment: The OP asked how to stream a large file, not how to prevent users from uploading large files.